# C Program - Removing duplicates from LinkedList

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying out on removing duplicates from a linkedlist. The user will insert one value and then, the program will check if the user's input and value in the linkedlist are the same. If it's similar, it will remove and leave only one in the linkedlist. For e.g. linkedlist=10 100. user=10. outcome=10 100 and not 10 10 100.

```
int insertSorted(LinkedList *ll, int item)
{
    ListNode *cur = ll->head;
    int size = ll->size;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if ((size - i) == 0 || item < cur->item)
        {
            insertNode(ll, i, item); // function to insert the value into Linkedlist
            return i;
        }

        cur = cur->next;
    }

    ListNode *current = ll->head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        if (current->item == current->next->item)
        {
            ListNode *nextNext = current->next->next;
            free(current->next);
            current->next = nextNext;
        }

        else
        {
            current = current->next; // only advance if no deletion
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can you also share with us the definition of `struct LinkedList`?

Comment: It contains head and size while ListNode contains item and next (node)

Comment: Is linked list a required data structure? If not, use any of binary trees instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you always return after you insert, you don't reach the code that deletes the duplicate. I think you need to `break` instead.

Also, where do you modify the size of the linked-list when you delete an element?
Should be reduced by 1 if I understand correctly.

In addition, since you clean duplicates after every insertion, you don't need the conditional advancement in the deleting loop

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the new node (the value 10 in your example), you then `return i;`, making the rest of the code, which I suppose checks for duplicates not to execute.